# Nitrous.IO and AWS Elasticbeanstalk initialization failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nitrousio

I am deploying a Rails 4.1 app through Nitrous.IO onto AWS Elasticbeanstalk. I have used autoparts to install the EB CLI 2.6.3. I managed to successfully push, and eb status gives a "Ready" and "Green" Health, but when I run eb init I always get a "Failed to update local Git configuration" message. However, it says the app is running and I can still push to it. I don't see the app in my AWS EB dashboard, I think because of that failed eb init command. I think the 'eb init' command has trouble finding where Nitrous has installed the EB CLI.